# Get list elements and its classes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I used `$('#ul li').get()` to get all the list elements and stored in an array, each of this list elements have classes...

```
var i;
var listClass = ('#ul li').get();
for(i=0;i<listClass.length;i++){
    var theClass = listClass[i].attr("class"); //<--what's the proper function/method/code for this?
    var content = listClass[i].innerHTML; //<-- works very well

    //other codes here
}
```

How may i able to get the classes of each list elements...Thanks!

Comment: as a note, you shouldn't really be using innerHTML - what is the content of the list items you are returning? is it text? a anchor tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery's own `map` to do that:

```
alert($('#ul li').map(function() {
    return this.className;
}).get());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MhVU7/

for example. You can do anything with the returned array.

The reason the way you're doing it isn't working is because you're calling the non-existent method `.attr` on a native DOM element - it's not an extended jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

```
var lis = document.getElementById("ul").children;
for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
  var li = lis[i],
      className = li.className,
      value = li.value,
      text = li.textContent;

  // code
}
```

Comment: +1 for recognizing that the OP didn't specifically ask for a cowbell solution. however from the looks of it I don't think yours is likely going to be understood of implemented. however correct it may be.

Answer (score 1):

The `get()` method returns a native array of DOM elements, not a jQuery object.

You should use jQuery:

```
var lists = $('ul li');

var className = lists.eq(i).attr('class');
var content = lists.eq(i).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop through all the elements

```
$('ul li').each(function(){
var className = $(this).attr('class');
var content = $(this).text();

});
```

Comment: what does $this reference? i don't think you understand what this keyword means.

Comment: seriously.. this code wont even work! `$this.attr('class');` refers to nothing.. should be `$(this).attr('class');` and even then attr does not do what you would expect it to do. I have corrected your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have commented the code to better help you understand it.

```
$("#ul li").each(function() { /* you should only be using # selector to identify id's - if it's all ul's you want just put ul. */
    var klass = this.className; /* this refers to the native DOM object, which contains className */
    var textContents = this.innerText || this.textContent; /* the text of the list, does not include html tags */
    var childNodes = this.childNodes; /* the child nodes of the list, each unencased string of text will be converted into a TextNode */
    console.log(klass + ' ' + textContents); /* replace console.log with alert if you do not have a console */
    console.log(childNodes);
});
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/4aYfk/) is an example of the above.

Good Luck!

Comment: ... Why use jQuery selectors but then do `innerText || textContent`

Comment: I like to mix things up - plus if we are going to move a community of cowbell enthusiasts over to the vegan vanilla way of life we must do it slowly. Crawl before you walk.

Comment: I mainly meant why not use `$(this).text()` and `document.getElementByiD("ul").childNodes`

Comment: I was making a mashup of vanilla and cowbell.

Comment: I know. i'm just objecting to the mashup being random rather then reasonbly chosen